# Hide form caption bar but keep the taskbar entry and borders?

Tags: c#, winforms, controlbox

I would like to hide the whole caption bar of a form while keeping the/a *title* in the task bar and form borders (like `Sizable`).

How do I do that?

Edit: **Windows (*Vista/7*) Explorer hides the title but has a name in the taskbar!**

Comment: So you want to hide the whole title bar while still displaying at title?  What about hiding the title bar and then just putting in a new text label as a stand in for the title?

Comment: Read the question to the end. Specifically the last 5 words in the first phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Set your form's `Text` property to what you want to see in the task bar and set the form's `FormBorderStyle` to `None`.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that I WANT BORDERS?